# How to test content with assert_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

'assert_tag' method is deprecated.
How to refactor this spec using only assert_select?

```
assert_no_tag :tag => 'p', :content => /Are you sure you want to delete this user/
```

Comment: assert_tag and assert_select are not related to RSpec, so I've removed those tags from your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to assert that the selector, matching a text, will return an empty array:

```rb
assert_select "p", text: /Are you sure/, count: 0
```